# How to add day to DateTime at end of month?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm creating a DateTime by adding a day to the current date (shown below).  I need the specific time set as shown below as well.  This code below works great until I get to the end of the month where I'm trying to add a day.

Can you help me change my code so that it works when the current day is at the end of a month and I'm trying to add a day so that it switches to December 1st instead of November 31st (for example) and throws an error.

```
var ldUserEndTime = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day + 1, 00, 45, 00);
```

Comment: Instead of creating a `DateTime` with explicit values, try using `dateNow.AddDays(1)`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0ccadae%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or maybe `var ldUserEndTime = DateTime.Today.AddHours(24.75);`. That is 24 hours and three quaters of an hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ldUserEndTime = DateTime.Today + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 45, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks Gary and everyone, I used this and it worked perfectly!!

Answer (score 13):

You just need to use [`DateTime.AddDays` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx) with using [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) to get it's midnight and add `45` minutes.

```
var ldUserEndTime = dateNow.AddDays(1).Date.AddMinutes(45);
```

Since there is no as a 31st day in [November](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/November), this constructor throws exception.

From Exception section on [`DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page;

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException - day is less than 1 **or greater than the
>   number of days in month**

Answer (score 6):

Maybe some kind of hybrid approach would work best for you so you can get the time component and add the day without having the trouble at the end of the month:

```
var ldUserEndTime = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day, 00, 45, 00).AddDays(1);
```

The `AddDays` method will automatically take into account the month rollover, so if today is the end of the month (hey, it is!), then you'll get `2015-12-01 12:45:00`.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
DateTime ldUserEndTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMinutes(45);
```